# Resume/CV using LATEX

Tags: cv

I want to prepare my CV using LATEX. Please provide some sample (latex source) so that I could see how does that actually render as PDF after compiling. Also, share some references for the packages/commands generally found useful for building a CV.

Any other relevant suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: The `moderncv` package has a bunch of examples that I suggest to take a look at.

Comment: your question is really too vague for the format of this site. If you click on the `{cv}` link below your post you will see dozens of examples